# How to cache a TensorFlow model in Django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, caching

In Django, I have this TensorFlow model:
`model = predict.load_model('path\model.h5')`
After the model is loaded, I want to keep it in memory such that I can use it multiple times without constantly reloading it.

I tried using the cache like this:

```
model = predict.load_model('path\model.h5')
cache.set('model', model)
```

when I try to retrieve it by:
`cache.get('model')`
I get this error:

Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ram://cf101767-7409-47ba-8f98-0921cc47a20a/variables/variables
You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.

Is there a different approach to keeping the model loaded ?

Comment: By caching the model, you can avoid the overhead of recreating the model for every request and instead reuse the already loaded model.
Please find this [link](https://elvanco.com/blog/how-to-cache-a-tensorflow-model-in-django) to cache a Tensor flow model in Django.